# Need powershell command to export Multiple "Teams Call-Queues" data in to a .csv FILE

Tags: powershell

I used to export all call-queues data when it was on skype platform without any issues, but with Teams platform, when i run the command to export and pipe the data into a .csv FILE, it never exports
"overflowactiontarget" & "Timeoutactiontarget" items. It populated that field for every call-queue as "Microsoft.Rtc.Management.Hosted.CallQueue.Models.CallQueue". The powershell i run is as below.

```
Get-CsCallqueue -first 100 |
    Select-Object Name,Identity,ApplicationInstances,RoutingMethod,DistributionLists,Agents,AgentsInSyncWithDistributionLists,AllowOptOut,AgentsCapped,AgentAlertTime,OverflowThreshold,OverflowAction,OverflowActionTarget,OverflowSharedVoicemailTextToSpeechPrompt,OverflowSharedVoicemailAudioFilePrompt,EnableOverflowSharedVoicemailTranscription,TimeoutThreshold,TimeoutAction,TimeoutActionTarget,TimeoutSharedVoicemailTextToSpeechPrompt,TimeoutSharedVoicemailAudioFilePrompt,EnableTimeoutSharedVoicemailTranscription,WelcomeMusicFileName,UseDefaultMusicOnHold,MusicOnHoldFileName |
    Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Append "C:\temp\CQdata.csv"
```

Comment: If you run this: `Get-CsCallQueue -First 1 | Get-Member | ? Name -In ('overflowactiontarget','Timeoutactiontarget')` ...do you see the two columns you're expecting?

Comment: Negative! Below is the output of the command

Comment: OverflowActionTarget Property   Deserialized.Microsoft.Rtc.Management.Hosted.CallQueue.Models.Target {get;set;}

Comment: If we do not pipe, it shows the full configuration. For example if i run Get-CsCallQueue  -First 1. This command displays all the information including 'overflowactiontarget','Timeoutactiontarget', but it doesn't display only when we use |

Comment: So if for some reason, you're having problems with pipe. Just eliminate the pipe. What if you use `$calls = Get-CsCallqueue -First 100; foreach ($call in $calls) { "do stuff here" }`

Comment: calls = Get-CsCallqueue -First 10; foreach ($call in $calls) { "select-object Name,Identity,ApplicationInstances,RoutingMethod,DistributionLists,Agents,AgentsInSyncWithDistributionLists,AgentAlertTime,OverflowThreshold,OverflowAction,OverflowActionTarget,TimeoutThreshold,TimeoutAction,TimeoutActionTarget,MusicOnHoldFileName" } | export-csv -notypeinformation -append "C:\temp\CQdatadec9.csv"     I am getting an error "An empty pipe element is not allowed" thank you

Comment: The whole purpose of this request was to export the call-queue configuration (multiple call-queues) into a .csv file so that it's easy to manage them like if i want to change the licenses on all the over-flow or time-out target accounts. We have around 900 plus call-queues , hence this request. At last i found a way to pipe it into a .csv file. Below is the powershell syntax.

Comment: Get-CsCallqueue -first 100 | select-object Name,Identity,ApplicationInstances,RoutingMethod,DistributionLists,Agents,AgentsInSyncWithDistributionLists,AllowOptOut,AgentsCapped,AgentAlertTime,OverflowThreshold,OverflowAction,@{Label="OverflowactionTarget";Expression={($_.OverflowactionTarget.Id)}}, @{Label="TimeoutActionTarget";Expression={($_.TimeoutActionTarget.Id)}} |export-csv -notypeinformation -append "C:\temp\macdec14cqdata.csv"

Comment: Chad! Thanks for your help.

Comment: Nice! Glad I could help.